# Uncaught ReferenceError: Parent is not defined

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, browserify, django-pipeline

I'm using django-pipeline along with browserify based on the documentation here -

http://gregblogs.com/how-django-reactjs-and-browserify/

I have it working perfectly fine when loading NPM/Bower packages like so -

```
'build_js': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'js/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
        'js/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js',
        'js/bower_components/react/react-dom.js',
        'datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
        'datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js',
        'js/node_modules/marked/marked.min.js',
        'js/node_modules/react-router/umd/ReactRouter.js',
        'js/child.js',
        'js/parent.js',
        'js/build.browserify.js',
    ),
    'output_filename': 'js/build_js.js',
```

The problem is I'm trying to reference the child.js and parent.js within the build.browserify.js

This is the contents of the 3 files -

child.js

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        and this is the <b>{this.props.name}</b>.
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

parent.js

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div> This is the parent. </div>
        <Child name="child"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

build.browserify.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I actually get 3 errors in my browser -

The following happens on my child.js and parent.js files both on line 4 -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And then I get this on my build.browserify.browserified.js at line 3

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Parent is not defined
```

This is the contents of that file -

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Parent, null),
  document.getElementById('content')
);

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

edit -

If I put all code in a single build.browserify.js file like this it works -

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        and this is the <b>{this.props.name}</b>.
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div> This is the parent. </div>
        <Child name="child"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're transforming the JSX properly? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` usually indicates that's the problem

Comment: If I put all the code in a single file it works fine.  updating to show that.

Comment: Are you also `require`ing all the dependencies in each file? ie, in parent.js: `require('/path/to/child');`

Comment: Tried that, specifically `var Parent = require('parent');` on a few variations of `Parent`, `parent`, `parent.js`, `./parent` etc. the files are all in the same location.  In any case I get the following error - Error: Cannot find module 'Parent' from '/var/www/app/static/js' which is where the module is in a file called `parent.js`

Comment: Did you export the Parent component using `module.exports`?

Comment: you've lost me on that as I'm new to javascript.  However, I did finally get a new message by doing `var Parent = require('./parent.js');` which I thought I had done before.  It is finding it now which I can see in my `build.browserify.browserified.js` file however now I get new errors like `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).` because it doesn't like that there isn't a prop on the `<Parent />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@taylorc93 is on the right track with this, but you're missing an additional step.

In addition to having to do `require('./parent')` in any file where you want to include the parent module, you also need to actually export the content of the `parent.js` file. So, `parent.js` should look like:

**child.js**

```
var React = require('react');

modules.export = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Child', // Always setting React component's displayName  will make your error messages easier to understand
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        and this is the <b>{this.props.name}</b>.
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

**parent.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var Child = require('./child');

modules.export = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Parent', // Always setting React component's displayName  will make your error messages easier to understand
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div> This is the parent. </div>
        <Child name="child"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

**build.browserify.js**

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Parent = require('./parent');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Also, while not required, it's good practice to give Component files uppercase names, just like you would class files in Java. Most apps will also name the root file as `app.js` or `main.js` or something like that, rather than `build.browserify.js` which is a bit vague since technically the file has nothing to do with building or with Browserify.

Comment: This is loading the files but it's complaining about the props being null which it doesn't do if I contain everything in one file.  Also, I don't need to call var React or var ReactDOM because it's being handled by django-pipeline/browserify.  This is the error I get with having the parent/child added - `ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Parent, null), 
    document.getElementById('content')
);` think it requires a new question though?

Comment: `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with `django-pipeline/browserify`. The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html) should answer the question about that warning. Basically, just do `React.createElement(Parent)`. Only add the `null` in if you also include the third parameter as stated in the docs.

Comment: For dealing with the props error, it's good practice do add the `propTypes` field to your components. That way if they aren't coming through properly React will give you fairly nice error messages explaining why.